# Remove start of binary file using FreePascal/Lazarus

Tags: file, binary, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I am almost finished with my first great undertaking in FreePascal/Lazarus, but this one problem has been bugging me.

The program needs to open a specific binary file (let's call it Test.exe), remove a specific amount of bytes from the beginning of the file (e.g. 2048 bytes) and write it out again. The size of Test.exe varies, but the amount of bytes shaved off the beginning alway remain the same.

I have been fiddling with both BlodRead/Blockwrite and TMemoryStream for the last couple of days, but haven't yet succeeded in this seemingly simple task.

This is probably a good indication that I have some studying to do about binary file handling. As this problem is really annoying me, I hope it is okay for me to ask you guys for help, and then build up my understanding through a form of reverse-learning: looking at the long-awaited solution, try to understand it, and research the unknown parts.

Thank you,

/Simon

Answer (score 2):

You simply need a couple of `TFileStream` instances, and use the `TStream.CopyFrom` method:

```
var
  FSInput, FSOutput: TFileStream;
begin
  // Create input stream (source file)
  FSInput := TFileStream.Create('Test.exe', fmOpenRead);
  try
    FSInput.Position := 2048;  // Set to whatever starting position
    FSOutput := TFileStream.Create('Test.new', fmOpenWrite);  // Create output file
    try
      FSOutput.CopyFrom(FSInput, FSInput.Size);  // Copy remaining bytes from input
    finally
      FSOutput.Free;  // Save new file to disk and free stream
    end;
  finally
    FSInput.Free;  // Free input stream
  end;
end;
```

If you need to end up with the original file name at the end, simply rename it before the operation, read in from that new filename and write out to the old name, and then delete the original file after you've released (freed) the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
var
FSInput, FSOutput: TFileStream;
begin

  // Create input stream (source file)
  FSInput := TFileStream.Create('Test.exe', fmOpenRead);
  try
     FSInput.Position := 2048;  // Set to whatever starting position
     FSOutput := TFileStream.Create('Test.new', fmOpenWrite);     // Create output file
    try
       FSOutput.CopyFrom(FSInput, FSInput.Size-FSInput.Position);  // Copy remaining bytes from input
    finally
       FSOutput.Free;  // Save new file to disk and free stream
    end;
  finally
    FSInput.Free;  // Free input stream
  end;
end;
```